# Set environment variables properly

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have to install very old software on a server. I have to perform this step but I get error:

```
[arbor@axapp01 3p]$ setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_07/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_07/jre/lib/security:/home/arbor/AX3.1_TC1/3P/curl/lib
Bad : modifier in $ (/).
[arbor@axapp01 3p]$
```

Looks like the step is wrong. Can you help me to fix it?

Comment: Why are you using `csh` syntax in a question labeled `bash`?

Answer (score 3):

Try writing it as

```
${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/...
```

instead.

Is this really bash, though? (You've flagged it as such.) It's csh that uses `setenv`. The bash version would be

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/...
```